# How to hide background image on textview

Tags: android

I've a `TextView` that shows a background image.

I need to show or hide this image depending at a condition (if x=1 show image, else hide image).
I'm using the code:

```
t1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ficha);
```

And it shows the image.

But I don't know how to hide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Reuben Scratton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127135/842697) is correct but deprecated in the new API versions. Another solution is:

```
t1.setBackgroundResource(0);
```